# Has any storyteller combined Zombies vs Vampires like

Tags: zombies, vampires

I envision a world where vampires defend humans from zombies, because vampires depend on (live) humans for food.

**Has someone already created that world?** Please forgive my ignorance.

Who fights who?

- Vampires primarily fight zombies.
- Zombies fight everything. They're kind of dumb.
- Humans are caught in the middle.

Why do I imagine that? After several years of zombie and vampire fiction, I have joked that it is time to combine those genres.

Answer (score 6):

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheExtinctionParade Zombies are overrunning the world, and the vampires in Malaysia decide to do something about it. 
It's not a happy comic.

http://lastblood.keenspot.com/main/2006/12/25/last-blood-begins/ Webcomic that was supposed to have become a movie, never happened. Interesting premise and plot, but never comes to a conclusion.

Google is helpful.